# How to load faster the Angular 6 inside Laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, angular6

So I have a Laravel project this is for the API purposes then inside the public folder I have stored there the Angular (folder named:borrower) I also changed the (file: index.html) base href="/borrower/"

to be able to load the Angular. I used redirect in web route: 
return redirect('/borrower/index.html');

so it will read the borrower folder inside the public but the loading time takes minutes, how can I make this more faster?

Comment: You need to see in network tab while debugging to inspect what is taking longer.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid - that file is vendor.js, If I do remove it , it will result broken page. vendor.js was generated in angular using ng build so I think it is important to include that during loading

Comment: What is the size of `vendor.js`?
It looks like the issue is with optimization of angular application not with laravel

Comment: @TalhaJunaid -  7.8 MB (23.82s)

Comment: @TalhaJunaid - thanks you give an idea when you mentioned "optimization"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk=true
```